# Summation of Arithmetic-Geometric Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I've been working through my homework paper, and I've come across this question. Now I'm confident in what I have done for the most part, but I am stuck at the end.

I have this recurrence relation, that I am supposed to solve using backward substitution.

$$
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n + 11
$$

Where n is some power of 2, for all n>1 and T(1) = 0.

I started out by some backward substitution and eventually arrived at this:

$$
2^3T(n/2^3) + 2^2(n) + 2^2(11) + 2(n) + 2(11) + n + 11
$$

And I reasoned that the general case was:

$$
2^kT(n/2^k) + 2^{k-1}(n) + 2^{k-1}(11) + 2^{k-2}(n) + 2^{k-2}(11)...2^0(n) + 2^0(11)
$$

n is a power of two, meaning that I can resolve this further:

$$
T(n) = 2^{k-1}(n) + 2^{k-1}(11) + 2^{k-2}(n) + 2^{k-2}(11)...2^0(n) + 2^0(11)
$$

Now I know I am supposed to summate this in some way, but I really don't know how! Can you guys point me in the right direction please?

**Second attempt**

I started from the beginning again, and this is how I went. I can see my answer coming closer to yours now, but I'm just struggling with one bit.

$$
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n + 11
$$

$$
T(n) = 2^2T(n/4) + n/2 + n + 22 + 11
$$

$$
T(n) = 2^3T(n/8) + n/4 + n/2 + n + 44 + 22 + 11
$$

Factorized the 11..

$$
T(n) = 2^3T(n/8) + n/4 + n/2 + n + 11(4 + 2 + 1)
$$

I'm struggling to get from this point to your answer. Sorry to be such a pain!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well $$\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} 2^j = 2^k-1$$ since it's just a geometric sum of ratio 2.

But let's check your substitution:
$$T(2^k) = 2 T(2^{k-1}) + 2^k + 11 = 2 \left(2 T(2^{k-2}) + 2^{k-1} + 11\right) + 2^k + 11$$ or
$$2^2T(2^{k-2}) + 2\times 2^k + (2 + 1)\times 11$$
Adding another term gives
$$2^2\left(2T(2^{k-3}) + 2^{k-2} + 11\right) + 2\times 2^k + (2 + 1)\times 11$$
or
$$2^3T(2^{k-3}) + 3\times 2^k + (4 + 2 + 1)\times 11$$

*Edit*: Note that you accidentally substituted in $T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) = 2T\left(\frac{n}{4}\right) + \boxed{n} + 11$. The boxed term should be $\frac{n}{2}$. Then you accidentally left out the $\boxed{2} \times 2^{k-1}$ and the $\boxed{2\times 2}\times2^{k-2}$ etc.

In general, we get
$$2^k T(1) + k 2^k + (1 + 2 + \cdots + 2^{k-1})\times 11 = k 2^k+11(2^k-1)$$
or
$$T(2^k) = (k+11)2^k-11$$

Comment: So is my substitution incorrect? I'm sorry, I'm really not following your explanation.

Comment: Yes - you forgot that when you substitute in for $T(n/2)$, you get $2T(n/4) + \boxed{n/2} + 11$

Comment: Oh jesus of course! I'll have another look and give it another go. :)

Comment: No worries! Sorry, I'll point it out in the answer for clarity. (I wanted to go through the whole question to make sure the technique worked easily, and there weren't any other mistakes.)

Comment: Hi, please look at my edit. I gave it another go but I hit a bit of a stumbling block, Sorry!

Comment: As I say in the edit, this time you *left out* too many factors of $2$! The $2$s outside the brackets exactly cancel the loss of factors of $2$ inside them.

Comment: Hey there. I think it's just hit me! When you factor out the n, then the n/2, then the n/4, you're also multiplying by the denominator because you're expanding it.. hence adding n each time.

Comment: Just beat you to it in the previous comment there; hope it's sorted now.

Comment: Yes thankyou! So this conclusion that I've got to now, which is the same as yours. That is the solution to the recurrence relation?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8361/discussion-between-sharkos-and-chris-cooney)